# Basic integer assignment

Tags: c

Here is what causes me frustration:

We have two integers: the one is of type `int16_t` and the other is `int8_t`. I have initialized both variables as follows:

```
int8_t short_int = 250    //This equals -6, and its binary representation is 0b1111 1010
```

So far so good.

```
int16_t my_int = short_int  //as we already know short_int is 0b1111 1010
```

For me, my_int should equal to 0b1111 1010 right? As 16bit integer the value 
0b1111 1010 has a decimal representation of 250. OK, but it doesn't.

Printing the value of my_int I get -6 which in binary representation is 0b1111 1111 1111 1010 **totally different** from `short_int` as a binary.

Comment: Search for and read about *sign extension*.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Or even better, don't. And instead read about conversions in C.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`int8_t short_int = 250` causes implementation-defined behaviour. The range of `int8_t` is `-128` through `127`.

Apparently your implementation generates the value `-6` for `short_int` here. OK so far.

But now you have to remember that C has *value-preserving* conversions.  If you convert `-6` to any other signed integral type it will still be `-6`, regardless of what its bit representation is.

Some people will talk about "sign extension" and other such stuff, however to understand how C works you just have to remember that the value is preserved unless it is out of range for the type; in which case it is either truncated (for unsigned types) or implementation-defined behaviour (for signed types; usually 2's complement truncation).

Comment: @KerrekSB updated. So the `intN_t` types have that requirement but the other signed integer types don't.

Comment: @KerrekSB why is it technically not overflow? `gcc` confused me with `warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion`

Comment: That's right. The type is also *optional*, i.e. ti doesn't have to exist.

Comment: @vsoftco it's not overflow (as defined by the C standard), it is out-of-range conversion.  Slightly sloppy by gcc. "overflow" is when an arithmetic operation would produce a result that is out-of-range.

Comment: @vsoftco: GCC doesn't always have the most helpful diagnostics (try compiling C++!). Overflow is what happens in an *expression* like `a + b`. The present situation is just conversion.

Comment: @KerrekSB What section of the standard says this is implementation-defined rather than undefined?

Comment: @Random832 6.3.1.3/3 "Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised."

Answer (score 13):

C works based on values not on bit-patterns.

If you assign an `int8_t` to an `int16_t`, both have the same value afterwards.

For negative values this means they have a different bit pattern (assuming a common representation of negative values).

Note that your `int8_t` is in fact negative.

Comment: 1+ for making the important point first. The rest is just details, and details can never provide the kind of insight that the real explanation does.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
int16_t my_int = (uint8_t) short_int;
```

instead of:

```
 int16_t my_int = short_int;
```

`short_int` is a negative signed integer so it undergoes sign extension when converted to `int16_t`.

Comment: I don't think "sign extension" is a thing in the C standard.

Comment: @KerrekSB I could quote the paragraph from the C Standard about integer conversion, but well I prefer to write about sign extension.

Comment: Well, that's your prerogative, but explaining high-level concepts with such low-level details is what encourages the kind of bit-pattern thinking that the OP was suffering in the first place...

Comment: @KerrekSB "sign extension", "sign extended" terminology is used intensively in the C Programming Language, 2nd by K&R which aim is to explain C to users, which is not the objective of the C Standard.

Answer (score 0):

Standard says

#### C11: 7.20.1.1

> The `typedef` name `intN_t` designates a **signed integer type** with width `N` , no padding bits, and a **two’s complement representation**. Thus, `int8_t` denotes a `signed integer` type with a width of exactly `8` bits.

When assigning `short_int` to `my_int`, number of bits of its binary representation increases while preserving the `short_int` sign and value (its called "sign extension").

`short_int` is negative and therefore `my_int` will have same sign with same value but with some padded bits.

Comment: No, this is not "integer overflow". This is merely an implementation-defined, value-changing conversion.

Answer (score 0):

ungur_gongor's answer is correct. If you really want to access a bit pattern as if it was `int8_t` or `int16_t`, you can use `union`:

```
union {
    int8_t short_int;
    int16_t my_int;
} converter;

converter.my_int = 0;
converter.short_int = 250;
printf("%d\n", converter.my_int);
```

Beware however of alignment (where is the padding for `int8_t`?) and endianness of `int16_t`.

This would preserve bit pattern (rather than value), although probably only on the byte which covers `short_int` (which is why I set `my_int` to 0 first).